# Non greedy regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I need to get the value inside some tags in a comment php file like this

```
php code
/* this is a comment
!-
<titulo>titulo3</titulo>
<funcion>
   <descripcion>esta es la descripcion de la funcion 6</descripcion>
</funcion>
<funcion>
   <descripcion>esta es la descripcion de la funcion 7</descripcion>
</funcion>
<otros>
   <descripcion>comentario de otros 2a hoja</descripcion>
</otros>
-!
*/
some php code
```

so as you can see the file has newlines and repetions of tags like `<funcion></funcion>` and i need to get every single one of the tags, so i was trying something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/(<funcion>)(.*)(<\/funcion>)/s",$file,$matches);
```

this example works with the newlines but its greedy so i've been searching and seen these two solutions:

```
preg_match_all("/(<funcion>)(.*?)(<\/funcion>)/s",$file,$matches);
preg_match_all("/(<funcion>)(.*)(<\/funcion>)/sU",$file,$matches);
```

but none of them work for me, don't know why

Comment: Just parse the XML.

Comment: @Blender it's not really an xml, its supposed to be inside a comment of a php file.. i'll edit it so it's more clear

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I just realized that the first example (2nd actually) you posted actually works perfectly here.

Comment: @Raphael_ well it doesnt work for me lol

Comment: It works fine in [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ClSBkY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `[\s\S]`, which means all space and non-space characters, instead of `.`. Also, there's no need to add `<funcion>` and `</funcion>` in match groups.

```
/<funcion>([\s\S]*?)<\/funcion>/s
```

Also, keep in mind that the best way to do this is parsing the XML using a [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php). Even if it's not a XML document, as you mentioned on your comment, extract the part that should be parsed and use XML parser to parse it.

Comment: the thing is that when I use `*?` my code doesn't seem to work and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 /<funcion>((.|\n)*?)<\/funcion>/i
```

**Eg**

```
$srting = "<titulo>titulo3</titulo>
<funcion>
   <descripcion>esta es la descripcion de la funcion 6</descripcion>
</funcion>
<funcion>
   <descripcion>esta es la descripcion de la funcion 7</descripcion>
</funcion>
<otros>
   <descripcion>comentario de otros 2a hoja</descripcion>
</otros>";

$result=preg_match_all('/<funcion>((.|\n)*?)<\/funcion>/i', $srting,$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**This one outputs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
   esta es la descripcion de la funcion 6

    [1] => 
   esta es la descripcion de la funcion 7

)
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Afg2pn)**

Answer (score 1):

This expression from your question:

```
preg_match_all("/(<funcion>)(.*?)(<\/funcion>)/s", $file, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This will work, but ONLY IF `$file` is a string containing the XML; if it's a file name, you have to get the contents first:

```
preg_match_all("/(<funcion>)(.*?)(<\/funcion>)/s", file_get_contents($file), $matches);
```

Also, keep in mind that PCRE has [backtrack limitations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit) when you use non-greedy patterns.

Answer (score 1):

. . If the structure is exactly like that (always indented inside content) you can easily match it with **/\n[\s]+([^\n]+(\n[\s]+)*)\n/**.

. . I always tend to avoid "lazy" ("non greedy") modifiers. It just kind of look as a hack, and it's not available everywhere and with the same implementation. Since in this case you don't seem to **need** it, I would suggest you not to use it.

. . Try this:

```
$regexp = '/<funcion>\n[\s]+([^\n]+(\n[\s]+)*)\n</funcion>/';
$works = preg_match_all($regexp, $file, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

. . The "$matches[1]" array will get you an array of the "funcion" tags contents.

. . Of course it would be nice to pre-filter the content and apply the RegExp on the comment contents only to avoid any mismatch.

. . Have fun.

Comment: @Raphael_ I learned to use Regex to be as strict as possible so that they won't match inconsistent data (and you will detect this data easier). It's not about _overcomplicating_, is just being a little stricter on the pattern. My example only works with properly indented content and will also return a cleaner result (already "trimmed").