# Strip tags (&lt; and &gt;)

Tags: php, regex, variables, str-replace

Im looking for a way to strip away `&lt;` and `&gt;` and everything in between these in PHP. And save it to a variable.

Example:

From this:
*`&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph with &lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt; text&lt;/p&gt;`*

To this: *`This is a paragraph with bold text`*

Anyone got an example or idea? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an example string?

Comment: @PeeHaa Example added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you do not have nested `&gt;` and `&lt;`, then you can try the following to match occurences:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/&lt;([\s\S]*?)&gt;/s', $string, $matches);
```

Try for yourserlf [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3On). Note the `?` in the query which makes the match in parentheses ungreedy.
You can find an answer to a similar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15150212/2032064).

If you want to strip away the values, then use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
<?php
$string = '&lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph with &lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt; text&lt;p&gt;';
echo "$string <br />";
$string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/&lt;([\s\S]*?)&gt;/s',
        function ($matches) {
            // do whatever you need with $matches here, e.g. save it somewhere
            return '';
        },
        $string
    );
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: Works great! Got any quick tips on how to append a space after each striped tag?

Comment: Nevermind... I figured it out. Thanks again for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The < encoding is html-encoding. To handle that, you want html_entity_decode() to decode or htmlentities() to encode.

Comment: This only partially answers the question

Comment: the example is : $stringConverted = html_entity_decode($stringToConvert); See the example on php documentation -> http://it2.php.net/html_entity_decode

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
$matches = array();
// Save
preg_match_all('!(<[^>]++>)!', $string, $matches);
// Strip
$string = strip_tags($string);
```

Or replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` if that was not a typo and you want to operate on already escaped string and use `preg_replace('/(&lt;.+?&gt;)/', '', $string)` to strip tags.